# What is the term of the concept to find the minimum vertex cover which covers all of the vertices (not edges) of an undirected graph only once?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, pattern-matching

I am actually looking for a term, I have googled for like past couple of hours and I had no luck so far.

So there exists a thing called, minimum vertex cover which implies " a set of vertices such that each edge of the graph is incident to at least one vertex of the set".

I'm looking for a similar concept only slightly different to the original, it is to find a set of vertices such that the set covers all of the vertices in a graph regardless of each edge is covered or not without any duplicates

For example:

Graph: [image: iamge]

Solution: [image: image2]

So the solution isn't a minimum vertex cover since all edges aren't covered, however the set of vertices do cover every other vertex in the graph without any overlaps/duplicates.

---

Edit credits to angryavian for a more concise question of my initial query:

Phrased another way: you want a minimal subset of vertices S such that the union of their neighborhoods is all the vertices, and moreover the union is a disjoint union?

Comment: Phrased another way: you want a minimal subset of vertices $S$ such that the union of their neighborhoods is all the vertices, and moreover the union is a disjoint union?

Comment: Yep! exactly that except no vertex in S should have the same neighbour. Reply to your new edit: Yes!

Comment: A minimal subset of vertices $S$ such that the union of their neighborhoods with themselves is all the vertices is a [Dominating_set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set). Together with the second constraint, which is being disjoined, I'm sure it always exists, my guess is it is not.

Comment: With the disjoint union constraint, I don't think such a set necessarily exists for all graphs. (Consider $K_3$ the triangle graph.)

Comment: So essentially, its a dominating set with disjoint union constraint. (i.e. Not something which is given its own name/term)

So you find all dominating sets and among them filter the disjoint union constraint one if it even exists?

Comment: The point is, finding minimal size dominating set is NP-Hard, So you and I can't find one in a reasonable time. And even if we did, and let me emphasize again, we can't, maybe it is the worst set with respect to disjointness. Your question is interesting, but it is asking for "too much". Even finding a set that is at most $c$ times larger than the minimal D-set is NP-Hard, for some constant $c$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A set of vertices whose (closed) neighborhoods partition $V(G)$ is called a *perfect code* (sometimes also an *efficient dominating set*). See for example Chapter 4 in [this book](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=C0JZDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA115&ots=taOWdwUP1X&dq=graph%20perfect%20code&pg=PA107#v=snippet&q=%22perfect%20code%22&f=false).

The term was first introduced [here](https://doi.org/10.1016/0095-8956(73)90042-7), extending the notion of [perfect codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_bound#Perfect_codes) from coding theory. In general a *perfect $d$-code* in a metric space is a covering with disjoint balls of radius $d$. In graphs the metric is just the usual distance, so balls of radius 1 are the same as neighborhoods $N[v]$ of vertices. In coding theory the vertices would correspond to words and the distance is for example Hamming distance; the idea is that if you select a vertex in the perfect code, then even after making one step in error, you will always be able to recover it (in a unique way).

Perfect codes are always independent sets (no two elements are adjacent) and dominating sets (their neighborhoods cover everything). Deciding whether any perfect code exists in a given graph is NP-hard, even in planar graphs (Theorem 4.4 in the book). If there is one, then all perfect codes have the same size (Theorem 4.2).

However, note that in the [Lights Out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lights_Out_(game)) puzzle you cite you don't actually need a perfect code. You need a set of vertices $S$ such that every vertex is included in $N[v]$ for $v \in S$ an *odd* number of times (instead of exactly once). The condition can be phrased as a system of linear equations over $\mathbb{Z}_2$, which can be solved in polynomial time! See for example [here](https://www.xarg.org/2018/07/lightsout-solution-using-linear-algebra/).

Comment: a **Perfect Code** is an independent set. This is another constraint, and resulting in the fact that the union of their neighbor does not cover all of the vertices. Also, it is not minimal in size.

Comment: Now I agree the question is about perfect code.